# Unable to add Teams App for Bulk of users in Office group and Security group (groups created via Azure AD Connect)

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Unable to add Teams App for Bulk of users for Office group or to a Security group (groups created via Azure AD Connect)

I have used the below API in order to add Teams app (side loading teams app) to set of a user in an Office group/Security group.

Working fine with the specific user. Also please let me whether this api will work with AD group ?

**Used graph explorer.**

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}/teamwork/installedApps
Content-type: application/json

{
   "teamsApp@odata.bind":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/appCatalogs/teamsApps/12345678-9abc-def0-123456789a"
}

**Error:**

"error": {
"code": "NotFound",
"message": "Unable to fetch license for user 'some GUID'.",
"innerError": {
"request-id": "some GUID",
"date": "2020-04-28T15:00:00"

Comment: The API works for a specific user. You can [add an team app to team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using graph API. there is no specific API for office group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning a custom app setup policy to users in a group

1.Install-Module -Name AzureAD

2. /*Skype for Business Online, Windows PowerShell Module can be downloaded and installed */
3. Import-Module SkypeOnlineConnector

   > $userCredential = Get-Credential 
   > $sfbSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $userCredential 
   > Import-PSSession $sfbSession
4. connect-AzureAD -Credential $userCredential
5. $group = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "TeamsApp"
6. $members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true | Where-Object {$_.ObjectType -eq "User"}
7. $members | ForEach-Object { Grant-CsTeamsAppSetupPolicy -PolicyName "Teams App Policy Test" -Identity $_.UserPrincipalName}

**Installation file for Skype for Business Online, Windows PowerShell Module**
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39366

**Reference**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-powershell-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/connect-to-all-office-365-services-in-a-single-windows-powershell-window

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/set-up-your-computer-for-windows-powershell/set-up-your-computer-for-windows-powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/manage-skype-for-business-online-with-office-365-powershell